# Is that possible to use two different filters for the AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, filter, adapter, autocompletetextview

I am working on a search bar of a small Android app.
I met this problem and I can't figure it out almost a week.

The basic idea is when user is typing on my search bar, I want to provide some search suggest for the users.
It is pretty a standard `AutoCompleteTextView` problem.

But it is complicated here for I have two different data source want to be suggested to users.
The first data (localData) is kind of fast and I want to suggest to users directly when user type something, and the second data (remoteData) I will send an Internet API request to retrieve the data and append the data to the previous one and update the dropDownList.

So I want to have two threads to `performFiltering` and the `publishResults` will be run two times, one is for local and another one is for remote request.

Is there anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe, that one is kinda impossible. You can sort your list of results and bind that to the ACTV.

What you can do is, hide an invisible container on the screeen and show that one while typing. =] And swap back to normal textview.

Comment: Hi benqus, what is the invisible container you are talking about could you provide more details? Thanks.

Comment: RelativeLayout with the property Visibilty.

XML: android:visibility="visible" or "invisilbe" or gone

JAVA: relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) or View.INVISIBLE or View.GONE

Answer (score 0):

I added an asynctask in the publishResults to achieve my goal.

When user is typing, firstly the dropdownlist will return the local suggest immediately, and will execute an asynctask. When my API request return the result, it will update the contents in the onPostExecute